# How to find out how many rows and columns to read from an Excel file with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

With the following code, I am able to read the cells out of an Excel file with PHPExcel.

I currently **manually** define how many rows and columns to read.

**Is there a way that PHPExcel can tell me how many rows and columns I have to read to get all the data out of the worksheet, e.g. even if some rows and columns are left blank?**

```
$file_name = htmlentities($_POST['file_name']);
$sheet_name = htmlentities($_POST['sheet_name']);
$number_of_columns = htmlentities($_POST['number_of_columns']);
$number_of_rows = htmlentities($_POST['number_of_rows']);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("data/" . $file_name);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array($sheet_name));
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("data/" . $file_name);

echo '<table border="1">';
for ($row = 1; $row < $number_of_rows; $row++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($column = 0; $column < $number_of_columns; $column++) {
        $value = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();
        echo '<td>';
        echo $value . '&nbsp;';
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

## Solution:

Thanks, Mark, here's the full solution with those functions:

```
$file_name = htmlentities($_POST['file_name']);
$sheet_name = htmlentities($_POST['sheet_name']);
$number_of_columns = htmlentities($_POST['number_of_columns']);
$number_of_rows = htmlentities($_POST['number_of_rows']);

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("data/" . $file_name);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array($sheet_name));
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("data/" . $file_name);

$highestColumm = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();

echo 'getHighestColumn() =  [' . $highestColumm . ']<br/>';
echo 'getHighestRow() =  [' . $highestRow . ']<br/>';

echo '<table border="1">';
foreach ($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        if (!is_null($cell)) {
            $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            echo '<td>';
            echo $value . '&nbsp;';
            echo '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

[image]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
```

and

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
```

or

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->calculateWorksheetDimension();
```

which returns a range as a string like A1:AC2048

although trailing blank rows and columns are included in these.

**EDIT**

or you can use the iterators to loop through the existing rows and columns to get each cell within the worksheets used range. See /Tests/28iterator.php in the production distribution for an example. The iterators can be set to ignore blanks.

Comment: Works well, I posted my solution above, nice to know about the iterators.

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of trailing blank rows and columns?

Comment: I found that LibreOffice can generate XLSX files with 4 rows, but PHPExcel reporting `getHighestRow()` to be over a million.

Comment: THat can easily be because there's something, not necessarily data, in the millionth row (print settings, styles, named ranges, etc)... it's why PHPExcel also provides a getHighestDataRow() method that is based on the actual cell records... and just because a cell doesn't contain visible data, doesn't mean that it doesn't exits

Comment: Mark, thanks for the great library. But the `getHighestRow()` and `getHighestDataRow()`  in version 1.7.9 are still recognizing an empty cell with date formatting applied to it as a valid data cell. I there any way around it?

Comment: @Ejaz I'm not going to make any changes to such an old version: but getHighestDataRow() will ignore empty cells even in 1.7.9; and the MS Excel definition of an empty cell is one that doesn't exist, non-empty cells can still contain a value like NULL or an empty string

Comment: @MarkBaker https://stackoverflow.com/q/62877428/12225746

Answer (score 9):

From the 1.7.6 and below `PHPExcel` versions it is possible to get worksheet information without reading whole file:

```
$objReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007"); 
$worksheetData = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($uploadedfile);
$totalRows     = $worksheetData[0]['totalRows'];
$totalColumns  = $worksheetData[0]['totalColumns'];
```

Comment: Just to add to this if you have a specific worksheet in mind you can match against `$worksheetData[0]['worksheetName']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much less cell reads than itterating all the rows(columns).

In my case, the first column is SKU of item and it's mandatory.

If you expect file with many many rows, in my case it can be 100 000 rows or more, i'm reading the value of the first column at every 10 000 row.

If cell A10000 is not empty, read A20000 and so on.

In this way, for a file with 100 000 rows I need max 10 reads of a single cell to decide in which segment of 10 000 rows the file ends.

For example, let say it's between 30 000 and 40 000 row.

Now get the average from above value - 35 000. One read of cell A35000 will further reduce the scope to 5000 rows. Next average (and the single cell read) will further reduce the scope to 2500 and so on.

Approximately you will need around 13-14 single cell reads, if you know in which 10 000 segment is the end of the file. If you expect file with 100 000 rows add maximum 10 cell reads to determine the exact segment of 10 000 rows. This means maximum of around 25 cell reads for file with 100 000 rows.

**Edit:** if you expect empty rows - read little more cells, for example, if you expect no more than 1 consequent empty row, read 2 consequent cells every time, for example A10000 and A10001, one of them should be non-empty, or you are beyond the end of the file. If you expect no more than 2 consequent empty rows, read 3 cells every time, for example A10000, A10001 and A10002, and so on.

Comment: For the curious, this is basically a rehash of the Two Egg Problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171966/two-egg-problem-confusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, you would have to loop through starting from say 1000 and go backwards until you hit the first non-blank cell and that would be your last row or column.

You can write a macro to do this in excel which may help but I don't know if you can execute it with PHPExcel.

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't handle Excel macros at present... and it's a pretty major task to implement them (although I have worked out the basic mechanics, it means writing a VB parser/sandbox in PHP, which is a large project in its own right)

Comment: And what will happen, if you expect up to 100 000 rows for example?
Will you start from 100 000 backward?
And what will happen if the file has 5 rows?
You are going to read 99 995 cells for nothing!
See my simple solution with very less cell reads (the answer from Nikolay Ivanov).

Answer (score 0):

Following [@nikolay's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613598/nikolay-ivanov)  thinking from answer above, I decided to make the first cell of every row mandatory. That way, I just look at each cell of each row first to find out how many rows actually have data, depending on the first row.

```
$uploadedfile = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(Yii::getAlias('uploads').'/'.$file_location);
$uploadeddata = $uploadedfile->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

    //we need to first know how many rows actually have data
    //my first two rows have column labels, so i start with the third row.
    $row_count = 3;
    // read through the data and see how many rows actually have data
    //the idea is that for every row, the first cell should be mandatory...
    //if we find one that is not, we stop there...
    do
    {
      $row_count++;
    } while($uploadeddata[$row_count]['A'] == "null");

    //get the actual number of rows with data, removing the column labels
    $actual_rows = $row_count-3;
```

Answer (score 0):

````
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('xls');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('file location here');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() AS $row) {
     $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
     $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); // This loops through all cells,
     $cells = [];
           foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                 $cells[] = $cell->getValue();
           }
     $rows[] = $cells;
}

//blade html
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach($rows[0] as $heading)
                     <th>{{$heading}}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
             @foreach($rows as $key=>$val)
                   @if(!($key == 0))
                        <tr>
                            @foreach($val as $value)
                                 <td>{{$value}}</td>
                            @endforeach
                        </tr>
                    @endif
             @endforeach
      </tbody>
</table>
```
````