# get row count with data of excel sheet by using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for bulk data import. While import the excel sheet I want to know the total row count of existing data. For that I am using the code,

```
$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
```

Now, I am trying to import an excel sheet, In that sheet having 800 rows. But the row count shows 65536 by using the above code. Actually I want to get the row count is 800.

The above code returns the empty row count also. But I need count of data existing rows. How to get that.
I am tried the below code also

`$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow();`

but it is also not working. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out how many rows and columns to read from an Excel file with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562527/how-to-find-out-how-many-rows-and-columns-to-read-from-an-excel-file-with-phpexc)

Comment: I tried this also. But not working. It returns 65536 rows.

Comment: i think you should check 65536 row number.. check it's empty or not?

Comment: You say "not working"..... that's getHighestRow() is based on the highest rowneed to code something yourself information stored in the Excel file itself, while getHighestDataRow() is based on reading the content of cells.... but a cell can contain a null or an empty string and will still be counted, so while you might not see that data, it's still there, so both these functions are working as intended.... if you need a different definition of empty, then you'll need to check the cells yourself

Answer (score 10):

To get the number of columns in your excel file you have to use the following code:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
```

and to get the number of rows

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
```

For your requirement, you should use the following

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestDataRow();
```

Use the `getHighestDataRow()` method to get the highest row number for cells that have actual content.

**Note that a blank space or a null value in a cell can qualify as content.**

From the 1.7.6 and below PHPExcel versions it is possible to get worksheet information without reading whole file:

```
$objReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007"); 
$worksheetData = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($uploadedfile);
$totalRows     = $worksheetData[0]['totalRows'];
$totalColumns  = $worksheetData[0]['totalColumns'];
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted all empty rows and try to import. But still showing row count is 65536.

Comment: are you using 1.7.6 or below than 1.7.6 version of phpexcel ?

Comment: 1.8.0 version of phpexcel

Answer (score 1):

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

echo count($sheetData)
```

it will return the row count.....