# getHighestDataColumn on phpexcelspreadsheet as count in php

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am using https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ phpspreadsheet to import files to database.I need to get the total number of columns in the uploaded excel before importing it to database.

I found getHighestDataColumn() which returns the highest coulmn as alphabets.

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($fileName);
$worksheet   = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$high=$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
dump($high);
die;
```

which gives output as `I`

Is there any way to get it as numbers ..??

Comment: Why not simply map the colum name to a number? Otherwise, there's `columnIndexFromString`

Answer (score 0):

If you only have A-Z you can convert the chars to ascii and get their int value using [`ord`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ord.php).

```
// Get ascii offset for alphabet
$start = ord("A");
$current = "I";

// Calculate char position from offset A
echo ord($current) - $start;
```

Comment: Thanks.But My excel may contain more than 26 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution as

```
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($fileName);
    $worksheet   = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); 
dump($highestColumnIndex);
die;
```

This will output the index of highestColumn ..